CouchDB cluster experiences 60s delay when a node is the last survivor, can this be avoided?
In CouchDB3 clusters provide horizontal scaling as well as durability, In attempting to take advantage of the durability, in a 3 node cluster if 2 of the 3 go down (when sharding is setup so that all 3 nodes have all the data) the remaining node will wait until a consistent 60s timeout has elapsed before it will return the data it has. Even if you anticipate this having been monitoring with _up, and attempt to use ?r=1 (or 0?) it still refuses to return any data until the timeout elapses.
Is this expected, and if it is can it be circumvented? 60s is an eternity for my use-case and project requirements.
The 60s seems to be coming from the irlang's net_ticktime, which is how log for it to decide a cluster node is offline. I can change this globally to a lower number, but I presume too low will be an issue.
is there some way ignore this on a per request basis?
